# Django Rest Framework urls router only recognized one path

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following `urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers
from TasksManagerApp import views

APP_NAME ='TasksManagerApp'

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'tasks', views.TaskViewSet)
router.register(r'task_templates', views.TaskTemplateViewSet)
router.register(r'task_lifecycle_nodes', views.TaskLifecycleNodeViewSet)
router.register(r'task_lifecycle_events', views.TaskLifecycleEventViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

For some reazon, DRF only recognizes one of the paths registered by the router: `task_templates`. All other paths are not recognized and rise a 404 error:

```
Using the URLconf defined in Attractora.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

es/ api-token-auth/
es/ admin/
es/ api-auth/
es/ rosetta/
es/ tasks_manager/ ^task_templates/$ [name='tasktemplate-list']
es/ tasks_manager/ ^task_templates\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='tasktemplate-list']
es/ tasks_manager/ ^task_templates/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$ [name='tasktemplate-detail']
es/ tasks_manager/ ^task_templates/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='tasktemplate-detail']
es/ tasks_manager/ ^$ [name='api-root']
es/ tasks_manager/ ^\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='api-root']
^media/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, es/tasks_manager/tasks, didn't match any of these.
```

I don't know why the router chose that one, it is not the first one to be registered, and all other paths are correctly registered too.

I have no idea where to look.

Answer (score 1):

I found the mistake (it was a very silly one). Only `TaskTemplateViewSet` was a **ModelViewSet**, all other where **ViewSet**s. As soon as I fixed it, everything worked.